# Why does changing the column type cause this error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray, type-inference, dtype

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("dirtydata.csv")
dfn = df.convert_dtypes()
bike_sales_ds = dfn.copy()

# Create new age column with general age range groups
age_conditions = [
    (bike_sales_ds['Age'] <= 30),
    (bike_sales_ds['Age'] >= 31) & (bike_sales_ds['Age'] <= 40),
    (bike_sales_ds['Age'] >= 41) & (bike_sales_ds['Age'] <= 55),
    (bike_sales_ds['Age'] >= 56) & (bike_sales_ds['Age'] <= 69),
    (bike_sales_ds['Age'] >= 70)
                ]
age_choices = ['30 or Less', '31 to 40', '41 to 55', '56 to 69', '70 or Older']

bike_sales_ds['Age_Range'] = np.select(age_conditions, age_choices, default='error')
```

[The dataset I'm working from](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MqVr5sy8WywUu8Y-QDRSp78HRUNzGoI/view?usp=share_link)

I didn't create this dataset. I got it from a youtube video a while back. The video wasn't about pandas.

The error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\dmcfa\PycharmProjects\Bike Sales Data Cleaning 01\main.py", line 43, in 
> bike_sales_ds['Age_Range'] = np.select(age_conditions, age_choices, default=0)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "<**array_function** internals>", line 200, in select
> File "C:\Users\dmcfa\PycharmProjects\Bike Sales Data Cleaning 01\venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 845, in select
> raise TypeError(
> TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

This gets around my error:

```
df.convert_dtypes(convert_integer=False)
```

But what is causing it in the first place? pd.info() says that the column is an Int64 whether I use df.convert_dtypes().

Comment: We don’t have your data. Provide a few lines of `dirtydata.csv` that cause the problem when run with your code. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me with my input dataframe. However, you can use `pd.cut` to check if the problem persists:

```
age_conditions = [0, 30, 40, 55, 69, np.inf]
age_choices = ['30 or Less', '31 to 40', '41 to 55', '56 to 69', '70 or Older']

bike_sales_ds['Age_Range'] = pd.cut(bike_sales_ds['Age'],
                                    bins=age_conditions,
                                    labels=age_choices)
```

Output:

```
>>> bike_sales_ds
    Age    Age_Range
0    87  70 or Older
1    25   30 or Less
2    70  70 or Older
3    55     41 to 55
4    33     31 to 40
..  ...          ...
95   89  70 or Older
96   79  70 or Older
97   67     56 to 69
98   71  70 or Older
99   78  70 or Older

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2023)
bike_sales_ds = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)})
```

Comment: I don't see convert_dtypes() in your code. That is what is causing the error. Did you try that as part of your test?

Comment: As you don't provide a minimal reproducible example that raises this error, it's difficult to test this specific case.

Comment: The second code block in my original post is how I modified the first code block to create this error. Did that code work for you?